# I can't disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth on Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, two-factor-authentication, 2fa

After upgrading my Magento 2.4.5 to Magento 2.4.6, I can't disable the 2FA extension in my local environment anymore.

This is the error that appeared.

```
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth because modules depend on it:
Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth: Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth->Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

[image: Magento 2.4.6 disabling 2fa]

How could I solve it?

Comment: Try this command :-  bin/n98-magerun2 module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth->Magento_TwoFactorAuth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to disable the new dependent module.

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Answer (score 1):

My choice - to create On/Off checkbox in Admin panel. I really don't understand why it is not built-in feature.

**Install this module or just copy code to your own repo:**
https://github.com/mygento/two-factor-auth

It's better solution - if you have several envs - you can easily enable 2FA on Prod and disable on other - without changes in `config.php` (enabling/disabling core module)

Answer (score 0):

You may run the following command:

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command and disable both module

```
bin/n98-magerun2 module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to run the below command to disable Two Factor Authentication and run the setup upgrade and di compile command. Finally, clear the cache.

```
php bin/n98-magerun2 module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
php bin/n98-magerun2 setup:upgrade
php bin/n98-magerun2 setup:di:compile
php bin/n98-magerun2 cache:clean
php bin/n98-magerun2 cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

The following commands were successful in disabling two Magento modules on Windows 10 xampp:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

After this I have encountered error "Unable to unserialize value, string is corrupted.", to resolve the error the Elastic Search was restarted. Afterward, some pages displayed incorrectly with CSS and showed a 404 page not found error. To address this issue, the following commands were executed:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

It is hoped that the above commands will be helpful to someone encountering similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

need to run the below command

**Step-1**

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

**Step-2**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```